# Is RedHat OS a must when using OpenShift?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat

OpenShift came from RedHat.

Does it mean I need to use RedHat OS when using OpenShift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKD (upstream, open source for OpenShift) uses Fedora CoreOS: https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/architecture.html#architecture-custom-os_architecture

OpenShift uses RHEL CoreOS: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.7/architecture/architecture-rhcos.html

These are the required operating systems because the cluster itself is actually tied to the underlying operating system to enable over the air upgrades.